# Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in php 5.1.6 in PHP excel library

Tags: php, linux

I have faced issued in PHP excel library

> `Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in`

I have PHP version 5.1.6 and Server is linux centos
i have also added the `extension=php_zip.dll`
;`extension=zip.so` in `php.ini` file

how i can remove this fatal error?

Answer (score 0):

AS per ZipArchive this is on ly works on (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL zip >= 1.1.0)
So after this solution i have added  and its worked for me.

I have installed php-pecl-zip using  below mention  command 
`yum install php-pecl-zip`
You can also check the extension is enabled or not using below mention code

`if (!extension_loaded('zip')) { echo 'zipless'; }else {echo 'Zipp';}`

Comment: Hold up. You asked a question, and then answered it yourself within seconds...?

Comment: Today i was stuck in this issue. After  solution implementation i have just shared my knowledge on this forum for other members .

Comment: Is there really adequate justification in asking/answering your own questions on long-outdated versions of PHP? The answer should at least recommend updating to a supported version of PHP

Comment: Note also that PHPExcel isn't recommended for PHP 5.1.6, with a minimum recommended PHP version of 5.2.0

Comment: Yes.Agreed .But  actually i have developed a application that used PHP excel library  and that my local server version was 5.3.3. and   When I have tried to upload this on live Server  then it was not working . I have observer that this issue is due to PHP version then i try to solve this issue and  found a solution on different  forum.  that's why i have added this solution on this forum

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly no guarantees that PHPExcel will run with PHP 5.1.6, because it has a minimum PHP version requirement of 5.2.0, although I do know people who are running it on the older PHP version using a more limited set of features.

If ZipArchive isn't available, then you may be able to use the slower and more memory-intensive PCLZip library that is bundled with PHPExcel, and can be enabled using

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

Note also that you really shouldn't still be running PHP 5.1.6 as it is no longer supported